# How to show button control on userform like a button in pop up mode without hovering mouse

Tags: vb.net

I have some button controls on userform where button style  selected is Popup. After running the code when I hover the mouse it show little tip tilted (or it show border on left and top edge).

How can I fix this for all button without hovering mouse where all button shows  border on its left and top (That will change it's visibility like a tip tilted button).

The purpose of this is, I want to show all button little over to it's parent form/panel as shown on the keyboard so that users can see these are the button without hovering the mouse.

I have attached button image and I want to all the button in the same style (This button style is popup). The button which is shown in picture give me a look when I hover the mouse over it (it displays the Left and Top corner with different/identical color) but I want this permanent to all button without hovering the mouse.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Button Image]

Comment: Can you provide some code about what you are doing?

Comment: Hi Jack, I do not have any code and I have added the button on window form manually. However, I have added an Image, you can have a look and also re-framed the question.

Comment: Only according your picture, I can do nothing for you. Please provide more information so that I can reproduce your problem.